# Transversality in Bourgeois Oancea's non-equivariant contact homology

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry

In their paper, "AN EXACT SEQUENCE FOR CONTACT- AND SYMPLECTIC HOMOLOGY", Bourgeois and Oancea defined, whenever there is sufficient transversality, a "non-equivariant contact homology". Essentially, this is a version of contact homology where the chain complex has two generators $\check{\gamma}$, $\hat{\gamma}$ for every Reeb orbit $\gamma$ corresponding to generators of $\mathbb{H}^*(S^1)$.

I've heard from a few people that one should be able to achieve transversality for this theory using $\mathbb{R}$ invariant time-dependent $J_t$ whenever one can rule out holomorphic planes (which are even more troublesome than holomorphic cylinders).

This is very surprising to me because Ritter in section 18.2 of his paper

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1781v5.pdf

specifically states that contact type $J_t$ is insufficient to achieve transversality for symplectic cohomology using quadratic Hamiltonians on completions of Liouville domains. This seems to be the very close to the non-equivariant contact theory. Moreover, in contrast to Hamiltonian Floer cohomology, for this equivariant contact homology we mod out the $\mathbb{R}$-action in the target rather than the domain.

Therefore, these $J_t$ are required to be $\mathbb{R}$-invariant (also I think this is necessary for the compactness theory) which is also a very strong constraint. The work arounds that Ritter develops for the case of quadratic Hamiltonians obviously don't apply for that reason. Certainly the arguments for the analogous claim in Hamiltonian Floer theory on compact manifolds (or for linear Hamiltonians in the Liouville domain setting) in Floer-Hofer-Salamon seems insufficient to adapt to this setting (because we require our complex structure $\mathbb{R}$-invariant and of contact type).

Question: What is the argument that one can achieve transversality in this setting?

EDIT: Perhaps the additional analysis I am interested in is carried out in this appendix B of version 2 of the paper by Hryniewicz and Macarini (this appendix B 
was later removed in version 3 for seemingly unrelated reasons).

http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.3122v2

Comment: I believe that Ritter's remark should be understood to mean that it is more delicate to prove transversality in that case than in the general case. Are you familiar with Dragnev's paper on transversality for cylindrical almost complex structures? (The key part of the idea is also explained at the end of Bourgeois's paper on homotopy groups of contact structures.)

Comment: @SamLisi Thanks I'll have a look at Dragnev (I had thought this proved transversality for somewhere injective curves for time-independent cylindrical J, which is obviously a related concept but not exactly the same). Do you know if this is the same thing as what Hryniewicz and Macarini do in their appendix ?

Comment: Your summary of Dragnev's paper is correct, but the same argument shows that you can obtain transversality in Ritter's setting with time-dependent cylindrical J, with some assumptions on the Hamiltonian. I'll get back to you about Hryniewicz and Macarini.

Comment: @SamLisi Thanks for your explanations, they are helpful. What assumptions do you have in mind for the Hamiltonian other than some time-dependent $H_t$, with non-degenerate orbits?